# Entity superclass with Generic ID of type ENUM

Tags: java, enums, eclipselink, jpa

Basically, I want to create an abstract class for some entities.
We use `EclipseLink 2.6.0` with most of the annotations from `javax.persistance` package.

The issue I am struggling with looks like this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class EnumKeyValueEntity<T extends Enum<T>, K> {

    public EnumKeyValueEntity() {
    }

    @Id
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private T id;

    private K value;

    /** getters & setters **/
}
```

### **PROBLEM**

And the real issue is isolated to: `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`. I would like to use this annotation so in database there would be a proper String instead of a number.

However, (I think) because it is an abstract class I get an error during tests. The source of it is described as:

```
[ERROR] Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7151] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
[ERROR] Exception Description: The type [class java.lang.String] for the attribute [id] on the entity class [class pl.ds.eemediation.storage.entities.EnumKeyValueEntity] is not a valid type for an enumerated mapping. The attribute must be defined as a Java enum.
```

But well, the `T` does extend `Enum`.

I also tried

```
 private Enum<T> id;
```

it complicates the later implementation and does not solve the issue :(.
What would be the way out of this?

Comment: maybe EclipseLink doesn't support generic TypeVariables in that way? It isn't a requirement of the JPA spec that implementations do, though I know the one I use does handle some TypeVariable cases. One thing you will need is to add @Basic on the "value" field if that is ever to work

Comment: value field works fine. it is only the @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) problem

Comment: Suggest you raise it as am issue on Eclipselink. I tried the same with DataNucleus JPA and it works fine, so while not strictly required by the JPA spec, it is a reasonable requirement to support that. Out of interest does EclipseLink allow Enumerated on an @Id? (not explicitly part of the JPA spec) if so then its just the TypeVariable with Enumerated that is the problem

Comment: @NeilStockton Yes. I specified Id Enumerated on the child class and it works for now. Thanks!